# Scripting in Redis: atomic execution

Tags: redis

In the [documentation about scripting in redis](https://redis.io/docs/manual/programmability/eval-intro/) the following is stated:

> Redis guarantees the script's atomic execution. While executing the script, all server activities are blocked during its entire runtime.

Do I understand that correctly that really **all** server activities are blocked? In the call to `EVAL` you state the keys that are modified, so why would Redis not only block activities for those keys?

Thanks in advance for any clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Redis runs commands one-by-one in a single thread. When it runs your script, i.e. `EVAL`, it cannot run other commands until it finishes the script.

So, NEVER run complicated Lua script, since it might block Redis for a long time, and hurt performance.